# Can we get separate artifacts drop folder for every build triggering in TFS

Tags: tfs, build, artifacts

I am always getting latest artifacts details in drop folder when I try to check for existing failed or success builds

Is there anyway we can get separate drop folder for each build process in TFS 2017

Answer (score 0):

Put the build ID in the drop folder path with `$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure about what you have mentioned in your question. `Is there anyway we can get separate drop folder for each build process`

If you are worry about that newly generated build results always overwrite the old one in the drop folder on build agent.

**Publish Build Artifact** task in new TFS vNext Build that you should use to control where and how your build output is produced.

[image]

In this case you could add variable in that path like `..\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Besides, you could also manually or add a script to download the drop folder after each build

[image]

---

If you just want to organize TFS build output into separate folders as mentioned`separate drop folder for each build process`

From

[image]

To

[image]

Please take a look at this blog: [How to organize VSTS build output into separate folders?](https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/HowToOrganizeBuildOutputIntoSeparateFoldersUsingVstsBuild)